# Python Pandas - how delete some columns

Tags: pandas, windows, csv

I have a file with many columns to be analysed with Pandas. How can I delete columns if the percentage of missing values is higher than a certain percentage value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please follow through this post. Whenever, you write a question, makes sure to add input data , what you have tried so far and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
threshold = 0.4 # Your value here
cols_to_be_dropped = []

for column in df.columns:
  if df[column].isna().sum() / len(df[column]) > threshold:
    cols_to_be_dropped.append(column)

df.drop(cols_to_be_dropped, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: OK all right. Thanks 1000